# Inspecting SAP Hana redo logs for change data capture

Tags: hana, cdc

I've been investigating how to read SAP redo and archive logs for the purpose of log-based cdc with SAP Hana as the source.  I see that HVR and Qlik Replicate perform log-based change data capture, however, I don't fully understand how they're able to do so.  Logs are stored in a binary format and I've not been able to find a command or API that allows these to be inspected.

Is this possible?  So far I've tried hdblogdiag with the content parameter to try and parse the logs but this doesn't yield the info I'd need (inserts, updates, deletes).  Any help on this would be appreciated as there's not a lot of documentation.  Based on how HVR describes the prerequisites, I'm imagining it's something that needs to be executed on the server where SAP Hana is running.

Comment: Well if it wasn't HANA I would suggest debezium, you may want to give a shot to Arcion

Comment: Well my goal is actually to write a connector for Debezium but I don't understand the mechanism other apps use to read the log files.  I had a look at Arcion but it unfortunately uses a more traditional trigger based approach.  Qlik Replicate and HVR are the two I've seen that do log-based